ArgoCD with Helm: is it possible to add more resources to application deployment?
I have created new application in ArgoCD in a path containing Chart.yaml and values.yaml, the Chart is based on a open-source remote repository in GitHub. Then problem occur, and the solution was to create a PersistentVolumeClaim and mount it to directory inside a deployed container.
I have created new pvc.yaml file but ArgoCD just ignore it during syncing. Like it was not existing in the directory. Is it impossible to add more resources if this app is based on helm? If yes, is there any workaround?

I don't think so. You could use the "multi sources" feature and two separate folders (or maybe a subfolder). Or use Kustomize to combine the Helm chart with additional resources. Or create your own chart including what you need.

In scenarios where I wish to customise a public chart without cloning it and modifying it, I use Kustomize to install the helm chart.
Note that you must enable the Helm Chart inflation feature in Argo CD, details here: Kustomizing Helm charts
This allows you to take full advantage of the public chart, but inject any additional resources in the chart that it was not designed to configure, such as your pvc.yaml.
You can also use patches: in kustomization.yaml to modify any aspect of the chart that had not been exposed for changing.
Here is a simple example using the ingress-nginx chart.
Your Argo App CRD needs to use the Kustomize install method instead of Helm for this to work.
# kustomization.yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

helmCharts:
- name: ingress-nginx
  repo: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
  releaseName: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  version: 4.11.3
  valuesFile: values.yaml

resources:
- pvc.yaml


Your Git repo would look something like this:
ingress-nginx/
├── kustomization.yaml
└── pvc.yaml
└── values.yaml

In our environment, we have something more complex to handle multiple environments, ours looks more like this:
ingress-nginx/
├── base/
│   └── kustomization.yaml
├── dev/
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── pvc.yaml
│   └── values.yaml
├── uat/
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── pvc.yaml
│   └── values.yaml
└── prd/
    ├── kustomization.yaml
    └── pvc.yaml
│   └── values.yaml


How I am adding features and resources to an existing chart that I don't control is to create a new helm chart, with the existing chart (your public chart) as a dependency.
You can then add the new pvc.yaml helm template into the /templates folder of that new helm chart.
One common pitfall is that the values for the dependencies go into the <name-of-dependency>: subtree in the values.yaml of the new chart.
In ArgoCD, you then reference the new chart.
